# Закрытый API - доступ открыт

Tags: java, android, модемы

Уже почти целую неделю ищу способы пробиться в `com.android.internal.telephony.IccCard` и овладеть методом `supplyDepersonalization()`. Тем, кто тоже будет копать в эту сторону - **ничего не получится**. Даже с помощью рефлексии - это невозможно.
Единственный способ (не знаю, первый ли я):

1. Найти на устройстве (с правами `root`) фреймворк модема `system/framework/telephony-common.jar`
2. Любым архиватором достать из него скомпилированный `classes.dex`
3. "Превратить" его в `jar` утилитой `dex2jar`
4. И добавить полученный архив в вашу среду разработки

Лично у меня AIDE и я просто разархивировал `android.jar` и добавил в его содержимое полученный ранее архив.

**В итоге**

Теперь мы можем написать в секции импортов, например, так

```
import com.android.internal.telephony.RIL;
```

И делать все, что хочется. Дело в том, что весь код, связанный с добавленными классами успешно скомпилируется и будет **выполняться**. Я это проверил, вызывая методы в разных классах и получая возвращаемые значения.

**Теперь к делу**

Собственно, сам вопрос, я пытаюсь получить интерфейс `IccCard` и делаю так

```
PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone(this);
Phone p = PhoneFactory.getDefaultPhone();
IccCard i = p.getIccCard();
boolean x = i.getIccLockEnabled();
```

В итоге приложение зависает (и даже не показывает простую разметку) при выполнении метода `makeDefaultPhone()`. Мне стало интересно почему и я полез его искать:

```
public static void makeDefaultPhone(Context context
    synchronized(Phone.class) {
if (!sMadeDefaults) {
sLooper = Looper.myLooper();
sContext = context;
if (sLooper == null) {
throw new RuntimeException("PhoneFactory.makeDefaultPhone must be called from Looper thread");
}
int retryCount = 0;
for(;;) {
boolean hasException = false;
retryCount ++;
try {
// use UNIX domain socket to
// prevent subsequent initialization
new LocalServerSocket("com.android.internal.telephony");
} catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
hasException = true;
}
if ( !hasException ) {
break;
} else if (retryCount > SOCKET_OPEN_MAX_RETRY) {
throw new RuntimeException("PhoneFactory probably already running");
} else {
try {
Thread.sleep(SOCKET_OPEN_RETRY_MILLIS);
} catch (InterruptedException er) {
}
}
}
sPhoneNotifier = new DefaultPhoneNotifier();
// Get preferred network mode
int preferredNetworkMode = RILConstants.PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE;
if (TelephonyManager.getLteOnCdmaModeStatic() == PhoneConstants.LTE_ON_CDMA_TRUE) {
preferredNetworkMode = Phone.NT_MODE_GLOBAL;
}
int networkMode = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.PREFERRED_NETWORK_MODE, preferredNetworkMode);
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "Network Mode set to " + Integer.toString(networkMode));
int cdmaSubscription = CdmaSubscriptionSourceManager.getDefault(context);
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "Cdma Subscription set to " + cdmaSubscription);
//reads the system properties and makes commandsinterface
sCommandsInterface = new RIL(context, networkMode, cdmaSubscription);
// Instantiate UiccController so that all other classes can just call getInstance()
UiccController.make(context, sCommandsInterface);
int phoneType = TelephonyManager.getPhoneType(networkMode);
if (phoneType == PhoneConstants.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating GSMPhone");
sProxyPhone = new PhoneProxy(new GSMPhone(context, sCommandsInterface, sPhoneNotifier));
} else if (phoneType == PhoneConstants.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) {
switch (TelephonyManager.getLteOnCdmaModeStatic()) {
case PhoneConstants.LTE_ON_CDMA_TRUE:
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating CDMALTEPhone");
sProxyPhone = new PhoneProxy(new CDMALTEPhone(context, sCommandsInterface, sPhoneNotifier));
break;
case PhoneConstants.LTE_ON_CDMA_FALSE:
default:
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "Creating CDMAPhone");
sProxyPhone = new PhoneProxy(new CDMAPhone(context, sCommandsInterface, sPhoneNotifier));
break;
}
}
// Ensure that we have a default SMS app. Requesting the app with
// updateIfNeeded set to true is enough to configure a default SMS app.
ComponentName componentName = SmsApplication.getDefaultSmsApplication(context, true /* updateIfNeeded */);
String packageName = "NONE";
if (componentName != null) {
packageName = componentName.getPackageName();
}
Rlog.i(LOG_TAG, "defaultSmsApplication: " + packageName);
// Set up monitor to watch for changes to SMS packages
SmsApplication.initSmsPackageMonitor(context);
sMadeDefaults = true;
}
}
}
```

Ну, что ж, внимательно почитав код и разобрав каждую строчку, я понял, что мне не нужно обращаться к `PhoneFactory`. Достаточно создать `Phone` самому. Пытаюсь так:

```
int cdmaSubscription = CdmaSubscriptionSourceManager.getDefault(this);
            PhoneNotifier sPhoneNotifier = new DefaultPhoneNotifier();
            RIL sRIL = new RIL(this, 9, cdmaSubscription);
            CommandsInterface sCommandsInterface = sRIL;
            GSMPhone gsmPhone = new GSMPhone(this, sCommandsInterface, sPhoneNotifier);
Phone sProxyPhone = new PhoneProxy(gsmPhone);
```

`DefaultPhoneNotifier` имеет конструктор с модификатором доступа `protected`. Причем, в официальной документацит его вообще нет (public). Мой фреймворк был модифицирован производителем. Что можно в таком случае предпринять? Можно ли создать `PhoneNotifier` как-нибудь по другому? Как отправлять код разлочки по-другому?

**UPDATE**

Фреймворк на тестируемом устройстве вовсе не модифицирован. Заметил, что в разных версиях андроида где-то `protected` есть, а где то нет.

Comment: на самом деле, через рефлексию работать с этими классами можно, но неудобно. У вас, возможно, не получалось, например, из за неправильного числа аргументов, передаваемых в метода, но проблема сейчас не в этом. Попробуйтесь пройтись под дебагом по этому методу, и выяснить, почему он зависает (я предполагая бесконечный цикл)

Comment: спасибо, что откликнулись :) А разве можно пройтись дебаггером по этому методу? И если да, то где дебаггер в AIDE? Случаем, не breakpoint?

Comment: насчет рефлексии - получалось вроде.. но все равно было неудобно :(

Comment: Вы серьезно? пытаетесь делать такие задачи в AIDE? Бросайте это. Это полнейшее извращение.

Comment: Видели бы вы приложения и игрушки, которые я создал в этом замечательном приложении. Благодаря его багам я узнал о разработке немного больше. Так, выходит, что дебаггера в нем нет?

Comment: Просто не нравится напичканность студии. С каждым обновлением все больше и больше неразберихи. Эмулятор не дождешься, слишком активные подсказки. Люблю когда пишу как хочу. Поэтому выбор пал на AIDE. Тем более у меня мало свободного времени, чтобы дома сидеть, приходится кодить на ходу/в поездке.

Comment: @metalurgus, посмотрите, пожалуйста, я обновил вопрос

Comment: Боюсь, [ждать его ответа уже не стоит](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3922/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE#comment12675_3924).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

жениться бы вам надо, барин...

Все что делает `supplyDepersonalization()` - это шлет модему команду `AT+CLCK="PS",0,<password>`. Проблема в том, что `PS` (т.е. *SIM Lock*) услуга давно не поддерживается производителями модемов (baseband).

Попробуйте послать модему команду `AT+CLCK=?` которая возвращает список поддерживаемых вариантов залочки. И если в нем не будет `PS` - то никакое извращение на стороне Андроида (application processor) вам не поможет.

Comment: вовсе нет, на одной модели получилось.

Comment: под *давно не поддерживается* я имела ввиду отсутствие кода реализации этой функциональности в новых версиях пакетов платформенной поддержки, которые предоставляются производителями чипсетов модемов своим заказчикам - производителям телефонов. в уже произведенных телефонах, где эта функциональность была включена изначально - она, конечно, никуда не делась. ваше *на одной модели получилось* никак не тянет на *вовсе нет*

Comment: а можно ли создать свой класс, унаследовать его от `PhoneNotifier` и переопределить все его методы? А потом просто `PhoneNotifier sPhoneNotifie = new MyDefaultNotifier()`?

Comment: и конструктор этого класса сделать `public`

Comment: не получается, в трех методах которые надо переопределить есть параметры с типом классов, которых нет

Comment: А вы сами замужем? :D

Comment: Автор, рано жениться. 18 лет только, дайте покодить :)

Comment: Отмечу ваш ответ как верный, так как он единственный. Я нашел другой способ и начал делать то, чем занимались в SuperSU. Только для другой цели...